# Creating new csv from multiple colums of individual csv's

Tags: python-3.x, csv

Cheers guys and gals,

thanks for helping me out already with the script I have so far, I have been on this site for hours these last days.

I still can't find a solution to my problem and the scrip is getting more and more complicated and messy.
The basic idea is:

- I have several csv files with measurement data
- I want to sort it after its Y and secondly after its X value (managed to get this far)
- I want to extract columns [5] (X-Values), [7] (Target Z-Values) and [14] (measured Z-Values)
- write a new file and add column [14] of the other documents to be able to build a mean of all the column [14] values

Afterwards I will keep on building more means and plot them, but that is going to take a while.

So far I got following script using python 3.5 (I am not sure how to paste it best, I hope pastebin's ok):

http://pastebin.com/50QSUrtr

I know it is not the easiest way to program it, but hey, I did it by myself and it works so far.

Thanks for you help!
JD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did below is have list of filename and iterate through the reading each csv file and append the columns indexed 5,7 and 14. Then I wrote it out to a new csv file.

```
    filenames = ["file1","file2","file3"]
    for filename in filenames:
        with open(filename+".csv","r") as file:
        list = file.readlines().rstrip().Split(",")
    newlist = []
    for row in list:
        row = [row[5],row[7],row[14]]
        newlist.append(row)
    for newrow in newlist
    with open("newcsv.csv","a") as file:
        file.writeline(str(newrow))
```